# The query returns values from column D, but there cannot be two values that have written "G" in column B, how to proceed?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

On this page (Presence) is Query, said in the question:

```
=QUERY(D4:H, "select D order by H desc limit 11", 0)
```

[image]

Already on this page (Name And Position) are the id's and the positions of the players:

[image]

As a rule, there can only be one goalkeeper playing on a team, so I need Query when defining the 11 players to be aware that if there is more than 1 goalkeeper (G) among them, the goalkeeper below the list needs to leave to be added. the next player on the list created by Query

[Link To Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fh2todBAFApGNyKw3f30p3pAAD3DHOVv6qqymHPxLyo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({SORT({D4:D, H4:H}, 2, 0), 
       IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT({D4:D, H4:H}, 2, 0),,1), 'Name And Position'!A4:B, 2, 0))="G", 
 COUNTIFS(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT({D4:D, H4:H}, 2, 0),,1), 'Name And Position'!A4:B, 2, 0)), 
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT({D4:D, H4:H}, 2, 0),,1), 'Name And Position'!A4:B, 2, 0)), 
          ROW(K4:K), "<="&ROW(K4:K)), 1)}, 
 "select Col1 where Col3 = 1 order by Col2 desc limit 11", 0))
```

[image: 0]